# We are tilling a table $a\times b$ with 3-tiles of shape $L$. Prove that $ab$ is even.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

So if we associate to cell $(i,j)$ value $x^iy^j$, then we have to find such polynomials with nonegative integer coefficients $A,B,C,D$ in two variables $x$ and $y$ such that $$A(x+y+xy)+B(1+x+y) + C(1+x+xy)+D(1+y+xy) = (1+x+...+x^{a-1})(1+y+...+y^{b-1})$$

Now if we put $x=y=1$ we get $3\mid ab$. But how to prove that ${2\mid ab}$

Edit: Daniel found a counterexample. Now what would sufficient condition on $a$ and $b$ be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ab$ need not be even:

$a=5;\quad b=9;\quad ab=45$

[image]

Comment: Clearly condition $3\mid ab$ is not sufficient. What would it be?

Comment: @nonuser As long as $3\mid ab$ and $\min(a,b)\ge 2$, then you can tile an $a\times b$ board, EXCEPT in the case where $a=3$ and $b$ is odd (or $b=3$ and $a$ is odd). This is the only exception, as proved by [Chu and Johnsonbaugh](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4363554/177399).